# Como setar linha somente leitura do GridView feito com DevExpress?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

Preciso colocar as ***linhas*** do meu `GridView` como somente leitura.
Ou seja, tenho um `GridView` que já contem alguns dados, estes dados não podem ser editados, porém posso adicionar novas linhas, e essas novas linhas podem ser editadas.

Porem estou utilizando o componente `XtraGrid` da DevExpress, versão 16.1

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // botao editar
    {
        editar = 1;
        readonly_false();
        gridLookUpEdit1.ReadOnly = true;

        int linhas = gridView5.RowCount;

        for(int i = 0; i <= linhas; i++)
        {
           // codigo para colocar as linhas como readonly = true.               
        }
    }
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando o evento `ShowingEditor` do `GridView`:

Primeiro, quando o usuário clicar no botão "Editar" temos:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // botao editar
    {
        // defino editar = 1, para saber que esta em edição
        editar = 1;
        // método para deixar os textbox editaveis (ReadOnly = false)
        readonly_false();
        gridLookUpEdit1.ReadOnly = true;

        // conto quantas linhas existem no GridView 
        it = gridView5.RowCount;
    }

// metodo ligado ao evento ShowingEditor
private void cell_readonly(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(gridView5.GetSelectedRows()[0] == -2147483647)
        {
            // ocorre quando clicado para adicionar nova linha
        }
        else if (gridView5.GetSelectedRows()[0] < it)
        {
            // ocorre nas linhas que já existiam.

            // cancelo a edição nas colunas com nomes entre ""
            e.Cancel = gridView5.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "DESCRIÇÃO" || gridView5.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "QUANTIDADE"
                       || gridView5.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "OF ORIGEM";
        }
        else
        {
            // ocorre nas linhas que foram adicionadas
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Para o GridView da DevExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011027/can-i-make-row-cell-value-readonly-on-xtragrid-just-for-one-row) você pode usar o [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event:

```
//...
var repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit();
repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly.Name = "repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly";
repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly.ReadOnly = true;
//...
void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
    if(e.RowHandle == 0)
        e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemTextEditReadOnly;
}
```

Para o .NET.

A propriedade [ReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx) indica se os dados apresentados pela célula pode ser editado. Você pode definir ReadOnly para células individuais , ou você pode fazer uma linha inteira ou coluna de células somente leitura , definindo as propriedades DataGridViewRow.ReadOnly ou DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly . Por padrão, se linha pai de uma célula ou coluna está definido para somente leitura , as células criança vai adotar o mesmo valor. Você pode substituir esse comportamento padrão definindo ReadOnly para células individuais .
Você pode navegar a uma célula só de leitura, e você pode definir uma célula só de leitura a ser a célula atual.
ReadOnly afeta apenas se uma célula é editável ; ela não afeta se o usuário pode excluir linhas .

No seu loop faça.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= linhas; i++)
{
   gridView5.Rows[i].Cells["colName"].ReadOnly = true;             
}
```

Comment: Está solução serviria se eu estivesse utilizando os componentes .net, porem estou utilizando os componentes da DevExpress. o `GridView` da DevExpress não contem o método `Rows`. Obrigado.

Comment: A bom, remove a tag .NET

Comment: Feito. Desculpe

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel, editado .

Comment: Não entendi, eu preciso colocar em readonly somente as linhas que ja existem no `GridView`, porém, pode ser adicionadas mais linhas, e essas tem que ser editáveis, ou seja, `ReadOnly = false`, nao entendi como este método pode me ajudar, vou editar a pergunta, para deixa-la mais clara, pergunta editada